# How to use ProGuard with NetBeans 6.7/6.8?

Tags: netbeans, proguard

Does anyone know how to integrate ProGuard with NetBeans 6.7/6.8 ? I've been using NetBeans for many years, but now I want to use ProGuard, is there a way to add it as a plugin and just click a button to start obfuscating my programs ? I know it exists in NetBeans Mobility Pack, how come it's not in the regular NetBeans version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple web search gave me

- http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/obfuscating-netbeans-java-appl
- http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/obfuscation

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wish Netbeans can have a button to enable Proguard without asking users to mess with the xml files.

Comment: The NB Wiki contains some (although quite old) info here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleObfuscation . I couldn't find any NB feature/plug-in after so many years. However, I've decided to use it from the command line: https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard