# Netbeans. Obfuscator type (PROGUARD) is not found in obfuscator classpath

Tags: netbeans, obfuscation, proguard

I'm trying to build my project obfuscated but It's not working.  I get this warning: 
Obfuscator type (PROGUARD) is not found in obfuscator classpath, using NONE.
Please use Plugins Manager to install the missing obfuscator library.
I looked at the plugins option but I don't know how to add proguard.

Answer (score 3):

Goto the **Tools > Plugins** then goto **Available Plugins** tab and search for `Proguard` you will have that listed. Tick the checkbox that follows it and press install.

You can see the screenshot below.

**EDIT** if you are unable to follow above steps then this might help you

1. http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/obfuscating-netbeans-java-appl
2. http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/obfuscation

I took the links from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164800/how-to-use-proguard-with-netbeans-6-7-6-8).

[image]

Comment: @Laural I have dited the answer. Check if it can help.

Comment: it seems Proguard was removed from plugins? :(, i saw your edit, but it would be so much easier if it could be used as a plugin..

Comment: @kaysush how do we use it with Java SE application?

Comment: @MohamedFarouk I guess this should work for all project types. I may be wrong though, it was ages back when I used it. Do give it a try, and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @kaysush I found this app it's worked for me [protect4j](https://doc.protector4j.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps here: http://mikkonieminen.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/netbeans-73-proguard.html
and it worked... I don't speak Finnish, but I think from the screenshots you can understand to add the beta2 repositiory for modules and then you can download the proguard plugin.
Good luck! Gergo

Answer (score 0):

If the proguard plugin is unavailable, you can add this plugin repository catalog at netbeans plugins:
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.3/uc/beta2/certified/catalog.xml

After installing proguard plugin, restart netbeans just to make it sure.